# Changing the blank user tile in Windows 7 Pro Classic Logon?

Tags: gui, windows-7, login

In Windows 7 Professional, when the classic logon option is enabled, i.e. enforcing ctrl-alt-del and not storing previous user names, the user name/password dialog shows a blank square for the user icon. Is there a way to place a generic icon (i.e. a company logo) into that default placeholder?

Comment: You should ask on superuser.com about this.

Answer (score 1):

Found this little tool after a bit of Googling, dunno if it will do what you want:

http://www.door2windows.com/ultimate-tool-to-tweak-modify-windows-7-logon-screen/

Comment: I'll have to look at it at work tomorrow, I don't have my test build here at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

A by product of having Windows 7 non remember the last user logged into the system is that there is no longer a hook for it to pull a user account picture...leaving you with a blank/empty frame.

I've been looking since implementing Windows 7 student labs in 09 for a solution.  The only lead I have come across was to look into keys set in the HKCU.Default hive in the registry, but I've come up empty thus far. Should something be found today to address this I'd be very happy.